# Parsing Alpha Vantage API with Gson/Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I was trying to parse the json data using gson. When I try to parse it with GSON, I always get a Malformed JSON exception

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 8 path $.Meta
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:947)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 8 path $.Meta
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:947)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
```

Here is a snippet of the raw response:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-08-28 17:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2020-08-28 17:00:00": {
            "1. open": "125.3000",
            "2. high": "125.3000",
            "3. low": "125.3000",
            "4. close": "125.3000",
            "5. volume": "703"
        },
        "2020-08-28 16:55:00": {
            "1. open": "125.3500",
            "2. high": "125.3500",
            "3. low": "125.3000",
            "4. close": "125.3000",
            "5. volume": "672"
        },
        .....
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

Although I can parse the json without gson, I am just trying to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the line where it is crashing:

```
TimeSeriesStocks tSeries = new Gson().fromJson(stringResponse, TimeSeriesStocks.class);
```

where

```
stringResponse = response.body().toString()
```

The response.body() is the response I get from the api. I can see that the response is fine.

And here is the `TimeSeriesStocks` class:

```
public class TimeSeriesStocks {

    @SerializedName("Meta Data")
    public LinkedTreeMap<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, String>> metaData;

    @SerializedName("Time Series (5min)")
    public LinkedTreeMap<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, String>> timeSeriesMap;

}
```

I tried adding LinkedTreeMap as type token but I got the same exception. I also tried using normal custom objects but the response.body() used to throw the error that the server is sending LinkedTreeMap as response. Although the issue looks pretty simple, I just wanted to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: "Although I can parse the json with gson"; what do you mean by that? I would expect the exception preventing you from parsing the JSON. Despite the provided stack trace being incomplete (it is missing the "Caused by" part) it appears your actual JSON (not the one you posted here) is malformed. Please provide the exact value of the `stringResponse` variable (first 15 chars should be enough).

Comment: Sorry it was the exact opposite: "Although I can parse the json without gson". I edited the question. The line which the stack trace points to is the one I mentioned. I have updated the question as well.


```
TimeSeriesStocks tSeries = new Gson().fromJson(stringResponse, TimeSeriesStocks.class);
```



stringResponse is actually ```response.body().toString()```

Comment: Thanks  for pointing out something that I thought wont be  wrong. Actually the jsonString was corrupt and was not what the gson was expecting. When converting the response.body(). the response structure I was getting was getting changed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my service layer which I never paid any attention to:

```
    @GET(endPoint)
    Call<TimeSeriesStocks> getTimeSeries();

    @GET(endPoint)
    Call<Object> getTimeSeriesAsString();
```

So when we calling getWeatherForUsersCitiesString() and performing response.body().toString()  was causing the issue and the json string was not what gson was expecting. The code I posted in this answer was where the actual issue was and not in the actual parsing of json.